# Django bulk_create update on duplicate fields

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model that mirrors a foreign data source, and sometimes the foreign data changes for old records.  I would like to bulk_create objects from the foreign data for speed, but I cannot find any documentation about updating on duplicate fields.

Example models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Book(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()  # Sometimes changes

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('author', 'title')
```

Running this in a creation loop is very slow (several minutes for a few thousand records) because every Book needs two transactions: one to get_or_create the author, another to get_or_create the Book.  Is it possible to use something like bulk_create and update the price when a Book matches on Author and Title?

Answer (score 0):

In the following I suppose that your foreign data source is 'morphological equivalent' to the following:

```
books = [{'title': 'Title1', 'author': 'author name 1', 'price': 23.50},
         {'title': 'Title2', 'author': 'author name 2', 'price': 24.50}, ...]
```

then you can update your model in this way

```
books_queryset = Book.objects.select_related()

for book in books:
   try:
     item = books_queryset.get(title=book['title'], author__last_name=book['author'])
     item.price = book['price']
     item.save()
   except ObjectDoesNotExist:
     # Add new item
```

Comment: I suppose the "add new item" section could be expanded into a bulk_create for new objects.  I am worried about what this would do for very large samples of books, but it seems like a start.